# ef.core error on azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I am experiencing the following error only on azure:

```
SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.)
```

The system is running .core 2 with ef.core and mssql.

If I use DB context provided by a DI then everything works fine, but if I initialise my own DbContext, then the error will appear.

The strangest thing, if I run a local copy of the code connected to azure's db then everything works fine, with no errors. The error only occurs  while the code is running in azure.

I don't know where to start debuging this...or why this error occurs on azure

Trace:

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, object providerInfo, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, uint waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, bool allowCreate, bool onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable+Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(bool buffer)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, TResult> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, ExecutionResult<TResult>> verifySucceeded)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute<TState, TResult>(IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func<TState, TResult> operation, Func<TState, ExecutionResult<TResult>> verifySucceeded, TState state)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute<TState, TResult>(IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func<TState, TResult> operation)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable+Enumerator.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, out bool found)
lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass17_1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute<TResult>(Expression query)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

In azure, go to application settings > Connection Strings , and set your connection string there.

For example, if you have your connection string set in your application.json, like this:

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "yourconnectionstring"
  },
```

Then your values under Application Settings > Connection Strings , would be as follows:

**Name:** DefaultConnection

**Value**: YourConnectionString

and select SQL Database from the drop down menu.

Hit save, let the application restart and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But, That was done before. The production database get migrated just fine and other operations which are using Dependecy Injected DB context working fine too.  The error occurs only if I initialise manually a db context, they fail. And once more...if I connect local copy of the code to azure's db, then everything works fine too.